# Need to change SearchView cursor color and underline color to white in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I need help on changing SearchView cursor color and under line color to white.. below is my code

```
            <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            style="@style/CustomSearchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close_white"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:queryHint="@string/search_store"
            android:searchHintIcon="@null" />

<style name="CustomSearchView" parent="MyMaterialTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">6sp</item>
    <item name="submitBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/label_input_color</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

To change color for line below search query, try define backgroundTint in your CustomSearchView style:

With backward compatibility support:

`<item name="backgroundTint">@color/colorWhite</item>`

If not work, try without backward compatibility support:

`<item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/colorWhite</item>`

However, this solution is not perfect due to it refer to other searchView elements.

Answer (score 0):

To change the Underline color

```
    View searchplate = (View)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    searchplate.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.DKGRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```